# GlideApp not found using LibraryGlideModule (Glide 4)

Tags: android, android-glide

Using Glide 4 in combination with okhttp3 and a LibraryGlideModule:

```
@GlideModule
public final class MyGlideModule extends LibraryGlideModule {

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide, Registry registry) {
        registry.replace(GlideUrl.class, InputStream.class, new OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory());
    }
}
```

The GlideApp class is not generated when building, while it is when I extend AppGlideModule. Using LibraryGlideModule there seems to be no generated Glide classes at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm working in a library, not an app project.

Comment: I ended up using AppGlideModule for now.

Comment: Follow this documentation http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/getting-started.html#applications

Comment: @Frank I don't understand purpose of LibraryGlideModule. Method of this class is never called. Me too. I must switch to AppGlideModule

Answer (score 15):

Glide v4 uses an [annotation processor](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/generatedapi.html) to generate an API.  This allows applications to extend Glide’s API and include components provided by integration libraries.

To generate the `GlideApp` api in your Android Project, do the following:

In your Android Studio:

- Click on the "Build" menu
- Click "Make Module " to generate the project-specific `GlideApp` Class.
- If  that doesn't work, rebuild the project using "Make Project"

Answer (score 8):

1. You need to create a new class `MyAppGlideModule` and extend `AppGlideModule` to it.

Refer the code below:

```
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule;
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule;
// new since Glide v4
@GlideModule
public final class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {
    // leave empty for now
}
```

2. Build -> Make Project

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use generated API (i.e. the GlideApp class) while using LibraryGlideModule. 
Reference:
http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/generatedapi.html#availability

"The generated API is only available for applications for now." (i.e. only available for AppGlideModule)

Answer (score 3):

If GlideAPP can't be generated

Attention: `annotationProcessor com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0`

Must be with `AppGlideModule Implementation class` In the same module

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another reason for the `GlideApp` class to not generate could be other errors in the project. So, if you've added the

```
annotationProcessor "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:${rootProject.ext.glideVersion}"
```

dependency, and set up a class which extends `AppGlideModule` and annotated properly with `@GlideModule`, then make sure scroll down in the `Build` View in Android Studio and make sure there are no errors other than GlideApp not found.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Kotlin, try to use `kapt` instead of `annotationProcessor`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding visual information for [@Abbas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889768/abbas) answer,

If the build error stops at a position like :
[image]

Go further on top and see this error:
[image]

In My case, it pointed out a Room Db error, which when fixed, fixed this error also (GlideApp not found).

So **fix the top level error first** and then try running the app again.